# Blocking some GTM tags when running TestCafe tests - use the dataLayer?

Tags: testing, automated-tests, google-tag-manager, e2e-testing, testcafe

Wondering the best way to prevent a GTM tag from firing.  I found https://rbardini.com/automating-gtm-data-layer-tests/ which tags about fetching the dataLayer variable and comparing it in an assertion, but this looks like a clumsy approach when you want to write to the dataLayer on every page.

For example, it suggests:

`const getDataLayer = ClientFunction(() => window.dataLayer)`

We use Google Tag Manager to automatically load tags on our website.  Unfortunately one of them is CloudIQ (from PayPal) which pops up an iframe overlay offering a newsletter signup or ability to save your shopping basket.  The Trigger in our GTM setup for that tag is simply 'All Pages'.  When it pops up it generally blocks our test because Selectors cannot be clicked.

Our page flow is over several pages of an online shop, e.g.:

- visit home page, click a product - navigates to a product page
- click some options on the product page, then add to cart
- go through checkout flow

So there might be many pages visited due to click actions.

There is an ability in GTM to define Variables and then use them in Exceptions for a tag, so I could prevent the CloudIQ tag firing either via a/ a global variable or b/ a dataLayer variable.  However, I can't see how to elegantly get these set for each page visited during my test, such that they would exist when the GTM examines variables in order to block a Tag from being loaded.  `Fixture.beforeEach` isn't right because it would only run once per fixture, and any data it set on the page's scope would be lost as soon as a page navigation occurs.

Anyone got experience of this sort of thing?

(The alternative of course is to detect the overlay, use switchToIframe to switch into the CloudIQ iframe and close it manually, but it pops up quite erratically and I'd prefer to simply disable the Tag altogether during tests as it's not core functionality of our website that we need to test.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way would be to set a custom user agent string to your test suite, create a custom javascript variable that returns the value for navigator.useragent, and make an exception trigger that blocks the tag.

Or any variation on that theme - set a cookie, use a url parameter, or if you test suite allow inject a global js variable, and check for the value in an exception trigger.

Comment: The user agent idea is nice. I need something that easily persists between page navigation, so the global js variable idea seems pretty difficult to maintain (I don't know if there's an "on navigation" hook).  I'll look into the user agent idea, not sure what effects that might have as I've never modified them before, just used them for clumsy browser/os sniffing. Thanks!

Comment: In the end I'm using dataLayer, i.e. `if (/TEST/.test(navigator.userAgent) { dataLayer.push({isTest: 'true')}); }` .. create a Variable in GTM for dataLayer element `isTest`. Create a Trigger type 'Custom Event' and _important_ set 'Event name' to regex `.*`, firing on the dataLayer Variable.  Then edit your Tag and add Exclusion with your Trigger. The big gotcha is the 'Event name' depends on your normal firing Trigger e.g. 'Window loaded' is `gtm.load`. Use `Preview Workspace` to debug and see the `_event` name. I use different events, so 'DOM Read', 'All Pages' etc have different `_event`.

Answer (score 3):

There is no need to avoid firing of events on the client side. Just mock the service routes for Google Tag Manager and CloudIQ and imitate correct responses for them.

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific please? What do you mean by 'service routes'?  My scenario is that I'm running testcafe on our live server and it executes chrome in headless mode, so I have a headless web browser loading our site, GTM and all its libraries.  I don't think I can sensibly intercept calls made by the CloudIQ library, unless you mean to change DNS resolution on that machine so they are routed to an IP address I control and mock them? That sounds like serious overkill, and besides is not suitable for a production machine :)

Comment: I should add - we are a small operation, we have a single linux server we can use, so I can't leave tests running on a second machine whose DNS I could modify.  Second, to mock CloudIQ I'd have to figure out its calling pattern, maintain my mock if they change their interface, and besides all that I don't care if it works or not, it's not core functionality I want to test.  My boss might choose to stop using CloudIQ at any moment, making all this effort pointless.  Using a user agent to play nice with GTM so it simply doesn't load CloudIQ is better for my scenario.

Comment: I believe @mlosev is referring to https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/test-api/intercepting-http-requests/mocking-http-requests.html#creating-a-mocker

Comment: Thanks @JohnKrull, I hadn't used the `RequestMock` functionality before, looks very useful! As stated, mocking the CloudIQ behaviour would be pretty much a waste of time in my case, the user agent approach is working well for me.